# Please help me find the correct answer in this sentence completion quiz

Tags: adverbs, sentence-structure, inversion

I am not sure which one is right between 2 and 4

> _________ home from the football field when it started to rain.

1. The boys walked with boredom
2. Boringly, walked the boys
3. Boring, the boys walked
4. Bored, the boys walked
5. The boys, boring, walked

Comment: 4 sounds the best, but I don't think any of them are grammatically incorrect. 1 doesn't even sound bad.

Comment: The answer is #4. #1 is actually grammatically correct but very awkward-sounding.#2 means the boys are the cause of the boredom which isn't correct. #3 is simply wrong and is almost meaningless. #4 as I said is correct. #5 is both grammatically awkward and wrong since it means the boys are boring and not suffering from boredom.

Comment: All of them are grammatically correct. Is there some other criterion to judge correctness?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's called an "opening adjective/adverb".

> **opening adjective** = an adjective at the beginning of a sentence, 
>   either as the first word of the sentence or as the first word in an 
>   adjective phrase
>
> **opening adverb** = an adverb or adverb phrase at the beginning of a
>   sentence, giving information about an action

It takes the form of "***Adjective/Adverb, subject + verb.***"  Having said that, the answer should be 4 (***Bored, the boys walked home ... .***)!
Check out pages 7 to 9 and 16 to 18 of the slide on this site:    http://www.slideshare.net/srgeorgi/opening-adjectives-and-adverbs

EDIT: Since I'm confident in what I believe is the answer for this question now after looking at various sites on opening adjectives and adverbs, I'm changing the "should be" in my "the answer should be 4" sentence to "is" now.

*The answer is 4!*

Comment: The reason I'm not sure is because I've never seen participle (like bored,) beginning in the sentence, and I suppose No.2 is inversion form. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: By inversion form, do you mean the subject and verb are inverted? I was thinking No. 2 meant that somebody walked the boys home, and the person bored here is the one who walked the boys home. I might be wrong though...